# Custom cite labels

Tags: biblatex

I came across this document that uses conference names (e.g., CCS16) as cite labels. I played around with `biber` styles without success. Any idea how is this achieved?

[image: bib]

Comment: `\bibitem` is just like `\item` and the label is given by the optional argument so `\bibitem[CCS18b] zzz` will produce what you show. the `\bibitem` could be produced by any number of ways, including simply writing that in a text editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention `biber` I suppose you are using `biblatex`. If this is the case, you could use the style `alphabetic` and specify `shorthand` to match the desired output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{CSS16,
    title={Something or other},
    author={E. M. Redmiles},
    year={2016},
    shorthand={CSS16}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
Go check~\cite{CSS16}!
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

(I first suggested to use the `label` field, but as moewe pointed out, it's safer to use `shorthand` to avoid the issues that will come up if you are using the `date`/`year` field)

Comment: That seems to be what's done---the labels in that document is also ordered alphabetically. Any idea how the author name is made bold face?

Comment: This is a different issue. Please ask a new question and provide a MWE

Comment: Note that you may not get the expected output if the entry in question has a `date` or `year` field if you use `label`. In that case `shorthand` may be safer.

Comment: @moewe good to know. I will add that